# Атрибут \r в конце каждой строки при записи

Tags: json, golang

В **txt** файле лежат строки в таком формате:

**string1

string2

string3**

Ну то есть разделенные `\n`. Я хочу получить массив с этими строками. Написал такой код, который должен получить данные в массив data и потом добавлять в массив `session.Data` если такого элемента еще нет, но он как то странно работает.

```
batch, err := os.ReadFile("text.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    data := strings.Split(string(batch), "\n")
    fmt.Println(data)
    for i, v := range data {
        if contains(session.Data, v) {
            fmt.Println("Element already added!")
        } else {
            session.Data = append(session.Data, data[i])
        }
    }
```

При отработке кода `Println(data)` выводит мне такое (в структуре в поле `session.Data` уже есть эти элементы)

```
 string3]
Element already added!
Element already added!
Element already added!
```

Почему мне криво отображается полученный массив, но `for` отработал как надо и сделал 3 итерации

Дальше я всю структуру прогоняю через `json.Marshal()` и записываю в json файл, туда записываются все 3 элемента, только на конце каждой строки добавляется `\r` что мешает мне потом нормально читать их в дальнейшем

```
sessionBytes, _ := json.Marshal(session)
    config, _ := os.OpenFile("config.json", os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    defer config.Close()
    _, err = config.Write(sessionBytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Successful update")
    }
```

Результат в **json** файле(**\r** нет только у последнего элемента, не понимаю откуда вообще берется)

```
{"Data":["string1\r", "string2\r", "string3"]}
```

Не понимаю почему не могу нормально увидеть полученный массив после чтения файла и почему добавляется `\r` при записи в `json` файл

Comment: Это перевод каретки. Делайте split с разделителем `\r\n`

Comment: Спасибо большое, нет времени углубляться в работу с файлами так как не основное над чем работаю, как будет время обязательно прочитаю как это работает. Сам был близок к решению но перепутал местами (\n\r) :D

Answer (score 0):

Это перевод каретки. Нужно делать `split` с разделителем `\r\n`, тогда и запись и отображение будет верным